# Best way to store/decode json inside struct mapping

Tags: json, go, maps, decode

I have a mapping inside a struct as follow :

```
type Red struct {
       **other 
       Tel map[string]string `json:"Tel"`
}
```

I receive my data json formated the following way

```
{
 "Params":[{"rewew": "tref"},{"Value": "x"},....]    
}
```

And i'm searching for the most effective way of populating my struct with the data so that

```
Tel["rewew"] = "tref"
Tel["Value"] = "x"
```

For the rest of the values it works fine when those are simplier values when doing this:

```
 var t Red
 decode := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
 decode.Decode(&t)
```

But i'm having trouble with maps

Comment: Your json doesn't match your struct. If you can change either one, you should use the solution given by Motakjuq. Otherwise you can define a custom MarshalJSON method for your struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON is

```
{
  "Params":[{"rewew": "tref"},{"Value": "x"},....]    
}
```

And if you want to map `Params` into `Tel`, your structure should be:

```
type Red struct {
   **other 
   Tel []map[string]string `json:"Params"`
}
```

And you can add new elements like:

```
red.Tel = append(red.Tel, map[string]string{"rewew": "tref"})
red.Tel = append(red.Tel, map[string]string{"Value": "x"})
```

But, I think there is a better way to do it if you're allowed to change the request AND the keys don't repeat themselves, using a JSON like

```
{
  "Params":{"rewew": "tref", "Value": "x"}    
}
```

The struct should be:

```
type Red struct {
   **other 
   Tel map[string]string `json:"Params"`
}
```

and you can use the data like:

```
red.Tel["rewew"] = "tref"
red.Tel["Value"] = "x"
```